# ASP MVC and Jquery ajax Search

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I wrote code for ajax search that return user info.

Controller  :

```
public JsonResult SearchPeopleByName1(string keyword)
{
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        ApplicationDbContext myDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var data = myDbContext.UserProfiles.Where(f =>
        f.ApplicationUser.UserProfile.Name.StartsWith(keyword)).ToList();
        return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Jquery :

```
        function Search() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/doctor/Home/SearchPeopleByName1/" ,
            data: "keyword=" + $('#appendprepend2').val(),
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#appendprepend2').text(result + "yes");
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Also i check controller, keyword passed to controller no problem and Query run okey and 1 row found . but jquery doesn't fill text box again...

Comment: Your trying to add a collection of objects to your element with `id="appendprepend2"` (whatever that is) which makes no sense

Comment: `result` is an array, not a single string value. Why do you want to fill an input element with an array ?

Comment: i try it by result[index number] , but it dosen't work my you explain me how can i extract array ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I try more than sample i was found on internet .... same as" result.Name" , "result[1]" but i just get message [object object] or [undefined]

Comment: i can do it with index value like this  $('#appendprepend2').val(result[0].Name); but when i use for loop for index it doesn't work! for (i = 0; i < result.count; i++) {
                        $('#appendprepend2').val($('#appendprepend2').val() + result[i].Name);

                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
        function Search() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/doctor/Home/SearchPeopleByName1/",
            data: "keyword=" + $('#appendprepend2').val(),
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                var i = 0;
                for (i; result.length >= i ; i++) {
                    $('#appendprepend2').val($('#appendprepend2').val() + result[i].Name);
                }


            },
            error: function(errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```